# TypeError: while building a keras model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to generate a siamese model and I am adding a final dense layer which calculate the pairwise distances between the set of pairs of input images for easier loss calculation later. The result should be an array which has single outputs for each pair of images vertically.

Code:

```
def pairwise_dist (A, B):  
    ''' Computes pairwise distances between each elements of A and each elements of B.

      Args:
        A,    [m,d] matrix
        B,    [m,d] matrix
      Returns:
        D,    [m] matrix of pairwise distances between each separate vertical pairs  pair of A and B
    '''

    output_list = []

    for i in range(A.shape[0]):


        # return pairwise euclidead difference matrix
        output_list.append(tf.sqrt(tf.maximum(tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(A[i] - B[i])), 0.0)))

    return tf.reshape(tf.stack(output_list),[1,len(output_list)])

def get_siamese_model(input_shape):
    """
        Model architecture based on the one provided in: http://www.cs.utoronto.ca/~gkoch/files/msc-thesis.pdf
    """

    # Define the tensors for the two input images
    left_input = Input(input_shape)
    right_input = Input(input_shape)

    # Convolutional Neural Network
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(64, (10,10), activation='relu', input_shape=input_shape,
                   kernel_initializer=initialize_weights, kernel_regularizer=l2(2e-4)))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D())
    model.add(Conv2D(128, (7,7), activation='relu',
                     kernel_initializer=initialize_weights,
                     bias_initializer=initialize_bias, kernel_regularizer=l2(2e-4)))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D())
    model.add(Conv2D(128, (4,4), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=initialize_weights,
                     bias_initializer=initialize_bias, kernel_regularizer=l2(2e-4)))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D())
    model.add(Conv2D(256, (4,4), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=initialize_weights,
                     bias_initializer=initialize_bias, kernel_regularizer=l2(2e-4)))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(4096, activation='sigmoid',
                   kernel_regularizer=l2(1e-3),
                   kernel_initializer=initialize_weights,bias_initializer=initialize_bias))

    # Generate the encodings (feature vectors) for the two images
    encoded_l = model(left_input)
    encoded_r = model(right_input)

    # Add a customized layer to compute the pairwise distance between the encodings
    L1_layer = Lambda(lambda tensors:pairwise_dist(tensors[0], tensors[1]))
    pw_distance = L1_layer([encoded_l, encoded_r])

    # Add a dense layer with a sigmoid unit to generate the similarity score
    prediction = Dense(1,activation='sigmoid',bias_initializer=initialize_bias)(pw_distance)

    # Connect the inputs with the outputs
    siamese_net = Model(inputs=[left_input,right_input],outputs=prediction)

    # return the model
    return siamese_net

model = get_siamese_model((105, 105, 1))
```

Error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-85-9ba3e962b271> in <module>
     44     return siamese_net
     45 
---> 46 model = get_siamese_model((105, 105, 1))
     47 model.summary()

<ipython-input-85-9ba3e962b271> in get_siamese_model(input_shape)
     33     # Add a customized layer to compute the pairwise distance between the encodings
     34     L1_layer = Lambda(lambda tensors:pairwise_dist(tensors[0], tensors[1]))
---> 35     pw_distance = L1_layer([encoded_l, encoded_r])
     36 
     37     # Add a dense layer with a sigmoid unit to generate the similarity score

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py in symbolic_fn_wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
     73         if _SYMBOLIC_SCOPE.value:
     74             with get_graph().as_default():
---> 75                 return func(*args, **kwargs)
     76         else:
     77             return func(*args, **kwargs)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py in __call__(self, inputs, **kwargs)
    487             # Actually call the layer,
    488             # collecting output(s), mask(s), and shape(s).
--> 489             output = self.call(inputs, **kwargs)
    490             output_mask = self.compute_mask(inputs, previous_mask)
    491 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\core.py in call(self, inputs, mask)
    714         else:
    715             self._input_dtypes = K.dtype(inputs)
--> 716         return self.function(inputs, **arguments)
    717 
    718     def compute_mask(self, inputs, mask=None):

<ipython-input-85-9ba3e962b271> in <lambda>(tensors)
     32 
     33     # Add a customized layer to compute the pairwise distance between the encodings
---> 34     L1_layer = Lambda(lambda tensors:pairwise_dist(tensors[0], tensors[1]))
     35     pw_distance = L1_layer([encoded_l, encoded_r])
     36 

<ipython-input-84-45055088321b> in pairwise_dist(A, B)
     11     output_list = []
     12 
---> 13     for i in range(A.shape[0]):
     14 
     15         # squared norms of each row in A and B

TypeError: 'NoneType' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

How to change the dense layer to make it work?

Comment: What is `initiliaze_bias` ?

Comment: np.random.normal(loc = 0.5, scale = 1e-2, size = shape)

Comment: And I assume `shape` is an `int > 0`  ? Becuase otherwise you will indeed get type = `None`

Comment: I have made some changes to code and error. If you are still here please comment.

Comment: How about you try with: `pw_distance = Lambda(pairwise_dist)([encoded_l, encoded_r])` instead of the two lines?

Comment: not working, I just need to get the shape of one of the outputs without error